# Manually move kernel image to /boot directory

Tags: kernel, boot, compiling, grub2

I have compiled my own kernel on Gentoo (following [the handbook](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:X86/Installation/Kernel)) and then I have moved the `bzImage` to `/boot/vmlinuz-4.0.5`. But when I boot the system I get the Grub2 shell. What am I doing wrong?

Also, when I try to boot the system from the Grub shell I got the following error: `kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0, 0)`. I also have Windows 10 installed on this hard drive.

Initially, `/boot` was a separate partition of 2MB but I discovered that I didn't need to do that and I removed any reference to that partition from `/etc/fstab` (basically, I removed the line from `fstab` concerning the `/boot`). Given the fact that after I rebooted the system I got the `grub2 shell`. I booted from an Ubuntu live CD and I built the kernel, after that I moved the kernel manually to `/boot`. I did it manually because `make install` (which should've handle this job) would have copied it to the wrong place.

These are the commands that I used in order to build the kernel from the Ubuntu live CD:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/a243b31a-80dd-4a49-8de2-f4417816981d/usr/src/linux$ make menuconfig
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/a243b31a-80dd-4a49-8de2-f4417816981d/usr/src/linux$ make && make modules_install
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/a243b31a-80dd-4a49-8de2-f4417816981d/usr/src/linux$ cp arch/bzImage ../../../boot/vmlinuz-4.0.5
```

Then I rebooted.

Comment: @FaheemMitha but do you hav any ideea why doesn't grub2 detect the available boot options or why it doesn't show the boot menu?

Comment: @FaheemMitha This is the guide that I am following https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:X86/Installation/Kernel. The fact is that I followd the guid first time. But after I rebooted the system I got the gurb shell. After a bit of research, I discovered that the only thing in `/boot` was `/boot/grub`. So I booted using a `ubuntu live cd` and compiled the kernel and moved it to from `arch/x86_64/bzImage` to `/boot/vmlinuz-4.0.5`. I did 80% of the steps described in the guide, excepting the `make install`, which would've copied the kernel to the wrong path.

Comment: @cristid9 Put all that information into the question, please. Also, it seems odd that a "official" guide would contain errors. Make sure you haven't make any mistakes following the guide. Can you provide more details about what `make install` was trying to do? Also, try asking on a Gentoo forum. Sometimes IRC channels are can helpful.

Comment: @FaheemMitha As far as I know, `make install` should've copied the kernel from `/arch` to `/boot`. I have asked this question on IRC, and I am waiting for answers.

Comment: So, where does it copy the kernel then? Can you paste the `make install` commands into the question? Again, put all relevant information into the question, not comments.

Comment: `make -n install` will show what the make would have done, but not actually perform any actions

Comment: @bsd Here is the output http://pastebin.com/9Mewdsqi.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error earlier when I manually copied the `bzImage` to `/boot`. However running `make install` fixed the issue for me. `make install` generates the `initramfs` image. The `initramfs` file is named

```
initramfs-4.12.0-rc3+.img
```

on my system

After you have both the `vmlinuz` and `initramfs` files, you need to run the `grub2-mkconfig` command

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

It will automatically generate the `grub.cfg` file and it will associate the kernel with `initramfs` file, like below

```
 --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.12.0-rc3+-advanced-1cd90ed5-08a6-4ca3-8b96-65b5a30382ae' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod xfs
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  f33e4ffc-4d5b-44be-aedd-7aacc6241ed9
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f33e4ffc-4d5b-44be-aedd-7aacc6241ed9
        fi
        linux16 /vmlinuz-4.12.0-rc3+ root=/dev/mapper/cl-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=cl/root rd.lvm.lv=cl/swap rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
        initrd16 /initramfs-4.12.0-rc3+.img
```

Comment: please go back and edit your post and add the code formatting please, without it your answer is very hard to read